# How Ants can eat Chili peppers also?

Tags: entomology

I captured a picture where ants feeding on **Chili peppers** also, I was shocked.

[image]

Actually this peppers is one of the best way to get rid of ants is to prevent them from ever considering from home.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @BryanKrause I edited my question, still is it unclear?

Comment: Yes it is still unclear you seem ask why the ants eat the pepper then state it repels them instead. Since I have never heard of chili peppers as an ant repellent, a source fr this claim might help. Are you asking why insects can eat chili peppers with no problem? The answer is capsaicin only works on mammals and possibly fungi.